# How to resize columns in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am new to ag-grid. As seen in the screenshot below, I have 4 columns initially. When I remove column 3 (test3), notice that there is space on the right that indicates that a column in missing. How can I ensure that once a column is removed, that the remaining 3 columns (in this case) will fill the area? I tried to pass `resizable : true` into `defaultcolDef` but that did not fix the issue...

[Intial View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZts6.png)

[View once Test 3 column is filtered out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgGKu.png)

Comment: use `api.sizeColumnsToFit()` after your delete operation to make sure the remaining columns fit the available width

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex: 1` on each column.

See the documentation here for more info: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#column-flex

Or checkout this plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/7evoWXCM1sChDBmX

Just drag one of the columns out of the grid to see it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the columnVisible-event to catch any columns added or removed

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-columns-columnVisible

and then call

```
gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#size-columns-to-fit